# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes as I scroll on Firefox tabs with 3 screens

Tags: firefox

It happened twice.
I have one HDMI screen plugged into my Lenovo laptop.
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Then another USB 3.0 screen from USB port (actually it takes 2 so using a USB 3.0 hub type gadget off of one USB 3.0 port on laptop).
I could not log out nor do the alt-printscreen-"REISUB" to reset.
I had to do a hard shutdown holding power button both times.
What could be the issue?

```
~$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7690036     2421544     2222912      406564     3045580     4559372
Swap:      10483704           0    10483704
```

@waltinator's recommendation, it looks like I have 1.5 times the SWAP space.
Most recently I was running Matlab, had Pycharm open, many firefox tabs, Youtube streaming at the same time.

Comment: Depending on the combined display resolution, it could be a lack of video processing power. Without knowing which Lenovo device you’re using and it’s specifications, though, all one can do is speculate 

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab fallocate` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: @waltinator I updated my question but it looks like I have ample swap space